# Assigning tasks to user based on work load

Tags: design-patterns, popup

I'm working on a pop up where you can assign percentages of applications to users based on current work load. For instance, I have 100 applications that need to be worked on and are not assigned to anyone. A user can click a button that opens a pop up window to assign percentages of those 100 applications to users (could be anywhere from 1 to 30 users). Let's say I have four users, and I'll assign each user 25% of the total application count. Next to each name, I want to display the number of applications already assigned to the user and the number of applications the user has already started to work on. The idea being that a person does not assign a higher percentage of apps to a person who already had a lot work on.

**My question:** What's a good way to visually show the person doing the assignment the workload of each of the users? I don't want to have possibly 15 rows of something like this (especially in a pop up):

John Smith *_*_% Current work load: 10 In progress / 12 Assigned

Comment: If each task is not very similar in terms of complexity and time needed, it is almost impossible to determine workload from task queues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Progress bars are an effective way of showing ratios and many amounts visually.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyVLXO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Note that writing the percentage of total applications separately would be redundant because you can tell the relative percentages assigned to each by comparing the sizes of bars between different rows.